# Updating Firestore data from a SwiftUI view in xcode not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

so i've made a XCode project where you are able to add data to Firestore and read it by searching for the saved data (serial number).
I now basically tried to combine those 2 separate views (search view + "form view") to get a 3rd view where you can search for the "serial number" and instead of getting the whole list of data, you get Text Fields with the data in it (like the view when you add it except that the fields are already filled in with the stored data).
So here are my problems:

- The text fields are kinda filled out, but just with the grey "placeholder" text. They should be filled out with normal Text which can be edited, just in case a dummie presses on save when they just edited 1 line and the whole data is gone
- If i write something in the text field and then press "Speichern"("Save"), it always creates a whole new document (that has a really strange ID style ([96251AF5-164A-4CBF-9BE6-9C9A482652DE ]) instead of changing the fields, and i was sitting here the whole day now, trying to get it working.

The whole code is kinda combined from 2 different videos. I Hope you can help me (yes, i know, it looks messy)

**Searchbar + Editing SwiftUI view**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentViewVier: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var data = getDataZwei()
    
    var body: some View {
       
        NavigationView{
            
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                
                GeometryReader{_ in
                    
                    // Home View....
                    Text("Bitte Seriennummer eingeben").foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                }.background(Color("FarbeSeriennummerStartbildschirm").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                
                CustomSearchBarEdit(data: self.$data.datas).padding(.top)
                
            }.navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}


struct CustomSearchBarEdit : View {
    
    @State var txt = ""
    @Binding var data : [Gerät]
    
    var body : some View{
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            HStack{
                
                TextField("Nach Seriennummer suchen", text: self.$txt).opacity(100).foregroundColor(.black)
                
                if self.txt != ""{
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        self.txt = ""
                        
                    }) {
                        
                        Text("Abbrechen")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                }

            }.padding()
            
            if self.txt != ""{
                
                if
                    self.data.filter({$0.sn.lowercased() .contains(self.txt.lowercased())}).count == 0 {
                        
                    Text("Es wurde kein Gerät mit dieser Seriennummer gefunden").foregroundColor(Color.red.opacity(0.6)).padding()
                    
                }
                
                else{
                    
                    List(self.data.filter{$0.sn.contains(self.txt.lowercased())}){i in
                            
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailZwei(data: i)) {
                        
                        Text(i.sn)
                    }
                         
                        Text(i.typ)
                    
                        
                    }.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 5)
                    
                }

            }
        
            
            
        }.background(Color.white)
        .padding()
    }
}

class getDataZwei : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var datas = [Gerät]()
    
    init() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("Geräte").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
            
            if err != nil{
                
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            
            for i in snap!.documents{
                
                let id = i.documentID
                let sn = i.get("Seriennummer") as! String
                let objekt = i.get("Objekt") as! String
                let str = i.get("Strasse") as! String
                let pos = i.get("Position") as! String
                let typ = i.get("Gerätetyp") as! String
                let ida = i.get("Installation")as! String
                let lg = i.get("LeasingOderGekauft")as! String
                let la = i.get("LeasingAblaufdatum")as! String
                let ga = i.get("GarantieAblaufdatum")as! String
                let nr = i.get("Hausnummer")as! String
                let plz = i.get("Postleitzahl")as! String
                let ort = i.get("Ort")as! String
                let vp = i.get("Verantwortlich")as! String
                let tel = i.get("Telefonnummer")as! String
                let zusatz = i.get("Zusätzlich")as! String
                
                self.datas.append(Gerät(id: id, sn: sn, objekt: pos, str: typ, nr: ida, ort: lg, vp: la, tel: ga, pos: objekt, typ: str, ida: nr, lg: plz, la: ort, ga: vp, zusatz: tel, plz: zusatz))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct dataTypeZwei : Identifiable, Codable {
    
    var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var sn : String
    var pos : String
    var typ : String
    var ida : String
    var lg : String
    var la : String
    var ga : String
    var objekt : String
    var str : String
    var nr : String
    var plz : String
    var ort : String
    var vp : String
    var tel : String
    var zusatz : String
}

struct DetailZwei : View {
    
   var data : Gerät
    @State var viewModel = GerätEditieren()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    enum Mode {
      case new
      case edit
    }
    var mode: Mode = .edit
    
    
    var body : some View{
        
        NavigationView{
            
            ScrollView{
        
        VStack {
        
        Group{
        
            Text("Gerät")
                .font(.title)
            TextField(data.sn, text: $viewModel.gerät.sn).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .navigationBarTitle("Geräteinformationen")
            TextField(data.objekt, text: $viewModel.gerät.objekt).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.typ, text: $viewModel.gerät.typ).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.pos, text: $viewModel.gerät.pos).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Text("")
            TextField(data.ida, text: $viewModel.gerät.ida).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.lg, text: $viewModel.gerät.lg).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.la, text: $viewModel.gerät.la).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.ga, text: $viewModel.gerät.ga).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
            Group {
                
            Text("Adresse")
                .font(.title)
            TextField(data.str, text: $viewModel.gerät.str).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.nr, text: $viewModel.gerät.nr).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.plz, text: $viewModel.gerät.plz).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.ort, text: $viewModel.gerät.ort).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            Group {
                
            Text("Kontakt")
                .font(.title)
            TextField(data.vp, text: $viewModel.gerät.vp).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField(data.tel, text: $viewModel.gerät.tel).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            
            Group {
                
            Text("Zusätzliche Informationen")
                .font(.title)
            TextField(data.zusatz, text: $viewModel.gerät.zusatz).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            }
            }.padding()
            .navigationBarTitle("Gerät hinzufügen", displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: { self.handleCancelTapped() }, label: {
                        Text("Abbrechen")
                    }),
                                        trailing: Button(action: { self.handleDoneTapped() }, label: {
                                            Text("Speichern")
                    })
                   // .disabled(!viewModel.modified)
                )
                }
            }
                }
                func handleCancelTapped() {
                dismiss()
                }
                func handleDoneTapped() {
                viewModel.save()
                 dismiss()
                }
                
                func dismiss() {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
    }






struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentViewVier()
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import Combine

class GerätEditieren: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var gerät: Gerät = Gerät(sn: "", objekt: "", str: "", nr: "", ort: "", vp: "", tel: "", pos: "", typ: "", ida: "", lg: "", la: "", ga: "", zusatz: "", plz: "")
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    enum Mode {
      case new
      case edit
    }
    var mode: Mode = .edit
    
    
    /*
    private func addGerät(_ gerät: Gerät) {
         do{
    let _ = try db.collection("Geräte").addDocument(from: gerät)
         }
         catch {
             print(error)
         }
     }
    */
    
     
    private func updateGerät(_ gerät: Gerät) {
        if let ID = gerät.id {
         do {
        try db.collection("Geräte").document(ID).setData(from: gerät)
         }
         catch {
           print(error)
         }
       }
     }
    
    private func updateOrAddGerät() { // (1)
        if let _ = gerät.id {
            self.updateGerät(self.gerät) // (2)
      }
      else {
        print ("error") // (3)
      }
    }

    
    func save() {
        
        
        func updateGerät(_ gerät: Gerät) {
          if let ID = gerät.id {
           do {
          try db.collection("Geräte").document(ID).setData(from: gerät, merge: true)
           }
           catch {
             print(error)
           }
         }
       }
        
        updateOrAddGerät()

    }
        
}
```

**Another Model (kinda)**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Gerät: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var sn: String
    var objekt: String
    var str: String
    var nr: String
    var ort: String
    var vp: String
    var tel: String
    var pos: String
    var typ: String
    var ida: String
    var lg: String
    var la: String
    var ga: String
    var zusatz: String
    var plz: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sn = "Seriennummer"
        case objekt = "Objekt"
        case str = "Strasse"
        case nr = "Hausnummer"
        case ort = "Ort"
        case vp = "Verantwortlich"
        case tel = "Telefonnummer"
        case pos = "Position"
        case typ = "Gerätetyp"
        case ida = "Installation"
        case lg = "LeasingOderGekauft"
        case la = "LeasingAblaufdatum"
        case ga = "GarantieAblaufdatum"
        case zusatz = "Zusätzlich"
        case plz = "Postleitzahl"
    }
}
```

Comment: To better understand how your project is set up, can you provide a screenshot of your data tree?

Comment: Check out this article for an overview of how to architect your app and update data in Cloud Firestore from a SwiftUI app: https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-update-data/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the replies. I was already able to solve my problem. Most of the code i used came from Peter's tutorials (which are absolutely great). The problem was, that i used the "setData()" method. Either i was just too stupid, or this method doesn't work anymore. I used the "updateData()" method instead and it works fine.